# IntelliJ JavaFx Project Runnable Jar is not executing

Tags: java, javafx

Currently working on a JavaFX project and I am loading the standardized HelloFX application. It is operational within IntelliJ by running it. However, when I create a runnable jar by creating an artifact, the created jar file does not work. I am using Maven plugin and Java 16. I have all the dependencies created and am using Javafx-sdk-19 jar files. I have watched countless youtube videos and have searched all over this forum to no avail. I am not sure if this matters but I am using Mac OS 16.2 on the M1 silicone chip. The error I am receiving when I try to run the jar from my terminal is shown below. I am new to Java FX so please let me know what else I should include to help troubleshoot this issue. I did not include the code because it is the customized application that comes with Intellij when creating a Java FX project. I have not tampered with the HelloApplication.java

[image: error message when executing runnable fat jar]

I confirmed that creating a regular jar using a swing gui executes without issue.

Comment: Please post error messages, stack traces, etc as text formatted as code.

Comment: Provide information so that this can be replicated ([mcve]).  How did you create the jar.  Review the packaging info in the [JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).

Comment: *"I have all the dependencies created and am using Javafx-sdk-19 jar files"* -> by all the dependencies, do you also mean JavaFX modules?  If so, those should only be provided either as dependencies in the pom.xml or as command line switches when using java dev tools, but not in both places.  So this statement is confusing to me.